# TextArea scrolling not working [Titanium]

Tags: ios, image, uiscrollview, textarea, titanium

I am creating an iOS app in which the user clicks an image and letter "A" is concatenated to a string variable.

Now, I have a text area with value of the variable string. The text area value is updated every time a new letter is concatenated to the variable string.

The problem is that when the width of the text area; the letters that are added after that cannot be seen. How can I make the last character entered to be always visible once the string length has exceeded the width of the text area?

Need a fix for this !

Code :

```
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
 backgroundColor:'red',
 width: 200,
 height:100
});

win.add(image);

var scroll = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
 top:40,
 left:230,
 width:290,
 height:50,
 borderRadius:10,
 backgroundColor:'transparent',
 scrollType:'horizontal',
 scrollingEnabled : 'true',
 showVerticalScrollIndicator:true,
 showHorizontalScrollIndicator:true,
 });

win.add(scroll);



var textType = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
 backgroundColor:'#E6E6E6',
 borderColor:'blue',
 borderRadius:10,
 top:0,
 left:-70,
 width:390,
 height:50,
 font:{fontSize:26, fontFamily:customFont},
 editable:true,
 enabled:false,
 textAlign:'right',
 scrollable:true,
 horizontalScroll : true,
 scrollType:'horizontal'
 });

scroll.add(textType);

image.addEventListener('click, function(e){
   string = string + "A";
   textType.setValue(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `horizontalWrap:true;`, which would make the text appear on the next line rather than off screen.

Or alternatively, set `scroll.contentOffset.x = textType.width - scroll.width` if `textType.width > scroll.width`. I'm not sure about the syntactical nuances of Titanium, but this is how you would do it in regular Objective-C / iOS programs.